# test output of bash backticks

Tags: string, bash

In a bash one liner, I would like to test the output of

```
someprogram --version
```

If the fist three characters of the output is "2.3" then the bash script
should continue, otherwise return non-zero

This is what I tried, but I'm open to other suggestions

```
$ [[ ${`ruby --version`:0:2} == "2.3" ]]
-bash: ${`ruby --version`:0:2}: bad substitution
```

I'm running "3.2.57(1)" of bash btw.

Update: how can I achieve my goal without "intermediate variables", without resorting to something like perl, without writing multiple lines of code, without utilizing external programs like cut.

Comment: You can't use variable operation on a subshell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use pattern matching:

```
[[ "$(ruby --version)" == 2.3* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you cannot combine it in BASH but you can do it old way using a pipe to `cut`:

```
[[ $(ruby --version | cut -c 1-3) = "2.3" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With grep, you can guarantee a compatible format:

```
[ "$(ruby --version |grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')" = 2.3 ]
```

`-E` is for Extended Regular Expressions (a.k.a. `egrep` on really ancient systems), which we use for `+`, and the `-o` will **o**nly show the matching text.

---

However, you won't be able to compare with that method, e.g. "x ≥ 2.3" or `[[ "$(…)" -ge 2.3 ]]`).  For that, I suggest `awk`:

```
ruby --version |awk '{
  split($2, V, /[^0-9]+/);
  for (i in V)
    if (!ver) ver = V[i] ".";
    else ver = sprintf("%s%03d", ver, V[i]);
  exit !(ver >= 2.003)
}'
```

This takes output like `ruby 2.3.3p123 (2017-12-15) [x86_64-linux-gnu]` and examines just the second field (`2.3.3p123`), the split that into an array `A` of `[2, 3, 3, 123]`.  The first item is taken as-is, with a dot after it, while other items are zero-padded to three places.  In this example, we'd end up with `2.003003123`, which is why I compared it to `2.003`.  Exit values are reversed (0 is true, other numbers are false), so I inverted the comparison for the shell.

That can be condensed down to this if you want it shorter:

```
ruby --version|awk '{split($2,A,/[^0-9]+/);for(i in A)if(!v)v=A[i]".";else v=sprintf("%s%03d",v,A[i]);exit!(v>2.003)}'
```

This can be run as: `if ruby --version|awk '…'; then …; fi`